expl3 \seq_set_split:Nnn in a \foreach loop
I'm trying to run \foreach over a nested list. For each iteration the value of the loop variable will be a list separated by semi-colons. To split the values I'm using \set_seq_list. It works when not within \foreach, it does not otherwise.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_ma_index_list 

\NewDocumentCommand{\remplielaliste}{+m}{%
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ma_index_list {;} {#1}
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\cp}{m}{%
  \int_compare:nNnT {#1} < {\seq_count:N \l_ma_index_list +1} {%
    \seq_item:Nn \l_ma_index_list {#1}
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\setlength\parindent{0em}

\begin{document}
  \remplielaliste{janvier; février; mars; avril}

  \textbackslash{}cp{1} : \cp{1} 
  
  \textbackslash{}cp{2} : \cp{2} 

  \textbackslash{}cp{3} : \cp{3} 

  \textbackslash{}cp{4} : \cp{4} 

\vspace{2cm}
\foreach \i in {{lundi; mardi}, {mercredi; jeudi}}
  {
    \i
    
    \remplielaliste{\i}
    
    \textbackslash{}cp{1} : \cp{1}  % here I'm expecting only 
                                    % 'lundi' and 'mercredi'
                                    % but it is printing 
                                    % 'lundi; mardi' and 
                                    % 'mercredi; jeudi'
                                    %
                                    % splitting is not done

  }

\end{document}


You need to expand \i before \remplielaliste sees it:
\expandafter\remplielaliste\expandafter{\i}

However, I believe it's better if you do it with just expl3.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_ma_index_list_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\lforeach}{m +m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\remplielaliste}{+m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ma_index_list_seq {;} {#1}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\cp}{m}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \l_ma_index_list_seq {#1}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength\parindent{0em}

\begin{document}

\remplielaliste{janvier; février; mars; avril}

\texttt{\string\cp\string{1\string}} : \cp{1} 
  
\texttt{\string\cp\string{2\string}} : \cp{2} 

\texttt{\string\cp\string{3\string}} : \cp{3} 

\texttt{\string\cp\string{4\string}} : \cp{4} 

\texttt{\string\cp\string{5\string}} : \cp{5} 

\vspace{2cm}

\lforeach{{lundi; mardi}, {mercredi; jeudi}}{%
  #1\par
  \remplielaliste{#1}%
  \texttt{\string\cp\string{1\string}} : \cp{1}\par
}

\end{document}


There is no need to check that the index is less than the count of the sequence, unless you want to add error checking. You see that \cp{5} in the first block prints nothing.
Finally, the name of a sequence should end with _seq.

probably you should explain why you replaced all concurrences of \textbackslash with `\string'. A backslash is not right for '{' and '}'?

@user1850133 The typesetting of \textbackslash{}cp is truly horrible… And \verb wouldn't work inside the loop.
